# Does anyone have an updated example on posting a JSON request?

Tags: java, json, xbmc

I am having a mess of a time finding up to date information on sending a JSON request to a local server.  I keep coming across examples that use deprecated code, and I'd really like to do this with code that isn't.

I can at least say that I now have a working example, and I am not receiving any deprecated messages from NetBeans, but I would like to know if what I've put together is the right way:

```
public void sendUpdateRequest() {
    String updateString = 
            "{\"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\", \"method\": \"VideoLibrary.Scan\"}" ;
    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(updateString, Consts.UTF_8);
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(getURL()); // http://xbmc:xbmc@10.0.0.151:8080/jsonrpc
    entity.setContentType("application/json");
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);
    try (CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build()) {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine()); // move to log
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); // move to log
    }
}
```

This is something I'm working on to update XBMC with a JSON HTTP request

**Edit**

Changed the code to try with resources per the comment -- hopefully this will be useful for someone else dealing with JSON and Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but I would like to know if what I've put together is the right way:

Yes, you are doing it correctly given the details you've posted.

The `StringEntity` contains the body of the request. You can set any appropriate headers there. Any other headers can be set directly on the `HttpPost` object.

As stated in the comments, don't take any chances, `close()` the `CloseableHttpClient` in a `finally` block.

Comment: And close() should be invoked in a finally block ;)

Comment: So I had that initially, but then the close() method wanted to throw another `IOException`, so I would be then doing another try/catch in the finally block -- is that poor coding?

Comment: @akevit No, it's just old school. Look into the new (Java 7) `try-with-resources`.

Comment: I was going to say, what if I did this instead: `try (CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build()) {` then I wouldn't even need the `close()` method correct?

Comment: @akevit That is correct. It would be closed once you left the `try` block.